# How to Break Lines in Lists with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a list that I created with HTML but I can't get the sentences inside the `<li>` tags to break and go down a line, without having to use `<br>`  for that. How could I break lines for lists?

Here is the HTML code below:

[image: image code]

OBS: after I set a width for `<ul>` tag it pins my content on the left side and not centered on the page

```css
.container h1 {
        margin: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;

}

.container h2 {
    margin: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0047FF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}


.container ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 35%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: white;
}

ul li {

    list-style: inside;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTIONS</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Learn to plan and set your goals so you get more done in less time.</li>
    <li>
      Discover the #1 way to create to-do lists to dramatically improve your daily performance and productivity.
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried using the `<br>` tag to line jump so that the text would go one line below, but I expected all lines in my lists to break one line in all my `<li>` tags

Comment: What do you mean by automatically?

Comment: yeah there's the /div, it just wasn't in the question

Comment: Set a `width` or `max-width` for either `.container` or the `ul`.

Comment: It worked! but my text went to the left side, and even with text-align: center is not positioned in the center of the page

Comment: setting a width caused lines to break but it fails to center in the center of the page

Answer (score 0):

You can put a space between each bulletpoint with something like

```
ul li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

But you're also missing the `<ul>` wrap around the list items:

```
<ul>
   <li>Learn to plan and set your goals so you get more done in less time.</li>
   <li>Discover the #1 way to create to-do lists to dramatically improve your daily performance and productivity.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it didn't work for me, my ul li still goes like this, without a line break: https://imgur.com/jTx0ZDA

Answer (score 0):

You can also use word wrap

```css
div {
    width: 250px; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
div.a {
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
    <h1>FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTIONS</h1>
    <li>Learn to plan and set your goals so you get more done in less time.</li>
    <li>Discover the #1 way to create to-do lists to dramatically improve your daily performance and productivity.</li>
</div>
```

It will look like this[image]

Comment: word wrap has not been working for me with lists

Answer (score 0):

you can not do that with giving `display:block;` to `<ul>`.

You can achieve 1 column centered list with this example;

```css
ul{
...
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
place-items: center;

}
```